# Vue 3 / Vuetify 3: how to set a global default color for buttons

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

Using `Vue 3` and `Vuetify 3.0.4`, I'm searching for a way to set a global default color for the `v-btn's` from Vuetify.

But this color must be editable when I want to set a different color on a specific `v-btn`.

On `Vuetify 2` the default color was grey for the buttons like in this example-

```
<v-btn
  icon
  tile
>
  <v-icon>mdi-trash-can-outline</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

now in `Vuetify 3`, I always have to write the `color="grey"` :

```
<v-btn
  @click="deleteAccountDialog(item)"
  variant="text"
  color="grey"
  icon="mdi-delete"
/>
```

**EDIT:**
I add the vuetify.ts content to show the theme settings:

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import type { ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'

const MyTheme: ThemeDefinition = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    primary: '#2196F3',
    secondary: '#424242',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    error: '#FF5252',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FFC107',
  },
}

export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'MyTheme',
    themes: {
      MyTheme,
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following trick could work for you-

Override the default color of Vuetify button in your global CSS, like this-

```
<style scoped>
  .v-btn {
     background: #F5F5F5;
   }
</style>
```

In this way, every new button would have a `#F5F5F5` color by default, and when you want to assign any other color, simply assign it using the color prop which would have priority over custom CSS.

```
<v-btn color="secondary">Button</v-btn>
```

See the demo here- https://codepen.io/nehasoni988/pen/RwBbwJg?editors=1010

Comment: thanks! that's what I needed. But needed to replace "background" to "color". Put that in App.vue and also with "!important"

Answer (score 0):

You are using the default dark theme of Vuetify and that's because your button is in black color which is #333333.
There are 2 approaches in my mind:

1. Change the theme color surface based on [this](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/) in docs.
2. You can create a component for your button with `grey` as the default color.

MyButton.vue:

```
<template>
  <v-btn
     variant="text"
     color="grey"
     icon="mdi-delete"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

and use it in other components like:

```
<template>
   <MyButton>Click Me!</MyButton>
</template>
```

Comment: I added my vuetify.ts file in the question. As the content shows, it's not a dark theme (dark: false).

Your 2nd idea would work, but I don't really like the idea of create a component just for a default color

Comment: so you can change the `surface` color in the theme but it changes everywhere

Comment: Yea, that's not really what I'm looking for. Thanks anyway

Comment: Hope you found the answer by now but if you didn't checkout the link below https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/global-configuration/